# How to combine two different keys into one to toggle in a virtual keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following an online tutorial i have created this virtual keyboard and added two different keys to open symbols and open numbers.
i want to know how to combine these two keys into one key that i can press to open symbols and press again to go back to numbers.

this question is a followup of another question about the same virtual keyboard if you like you can check it out but its basically the same code here without added buttons.

```js
const keyLayout = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "backspace",
  "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
  "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",
  "symbols", "numbers", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
  "space"
];
const SymbolLayout = [
  "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "backspace",
  "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
  "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",
  "symbols", "numbers", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
  "space"
];

const Keyboard = {
  elements: {
    main: null,
    keysContainer: null,
    keys: []
  },

  eventHandlers: {
    oninput: null,
    onclose: null
  },

  properties: {
    value: "",
    capsLock: false
  },

  init() {
    // Create main elements
    this.elements.main = document.createElement("div");
    this.elements.keysContainer = document.createElement("div");

    // Setup main elements
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard", "keyboard--hidden");
    this.elements.keysContainer.classList.add("keyboard__keys");
    this.setLayout(keyLayout);

    // Add to DOM
    this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
    document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);

    // Automatically use keyboard for elements with .use-keyboard-input
    document.querySelectorAll(".use-keyboard-input").forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        this.open(element.value, currentValue => {
          element.value = currentValue;
        });
      });
    });
  },
  setLayout(layout) {
    this.elements.keysContainer.innerHTML = "";
    this.elements.keysContainer.appendChild(this._createKeys(layout));
    this.elements.keys = this.elements.keysContainer.querySelectorAll(".keyboard__key");
  },
  _createKeys(layout) {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // Creates HTML for an icon
    const createIconHTML = (icon_name) => {
      return `<i class="material-icons">${icon_name}</i>`;
    };

    layout.forEach(key => {
      const keyElement = document.createElement("button");
      const insertLineBreak = ["backspace", "p", "enter", "?"].indexOf(key) !== -1;


      // Add attributes/classes
      keyElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
      keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key");

      switch (key) {
        case "backspace":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("backspace");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(0, this.properties.value.length - 1);
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "caps":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--activatable");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_capslock");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this._toggleCapsLock();
            keyElement.classList.toggle("keyboard__key--active", this.properties.capsLock);
          });

          break;

        case "enter":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_return");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += "\n";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "space":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--extra-wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("space_bar");
          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {

            this.properties.value += " ";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "symbols":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerText = "!#*$";

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.setLayout(SymbolLayout);
          });



          break;
        case "numbers":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerText = "123";

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.setLayout(keyLayout);
          });

          break;

        default:
          keyElement.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;
      }

      fragment.appendChild(keyElement);

      if (insertLineBreak) {
        fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      }
    });

    return fragment;
  },

  _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
    if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
      this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
    }
  },

  _toggleCapsLock() {
    this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

    for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
      if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
        key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock ? key.textContent.toUpperCase() : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  },

  open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
    this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.remove("keyboard--hidden");
  },

  close() {
    this.properties.value = "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard--hidden");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  Keyboard.init();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: rgb(54, 49, 49);
}

.use-keyboard-input {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.678);
  border: 2px solid rgb(107, 104, 104);
  border-radius: 10%;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.keyboard {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: transparent;
  user-select: none;
  transition: bottom 0.4s;
}

.keyboard--hidden {
  bottom: -100%;
}

.keyboard__keys {
  text-align: center;
}

.keyboard__key {
  height: 45px;
  width: 6%;
  max-width: 90px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(218, 190, 218, 0.589);
  color: #0c0101;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.keyboard__key::after {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.keyboard__key:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.keyboard__key--wide {
  width: 12%;
}

.keyboard__key--extra-wide {
  width: 36%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.keyboard__key--dark {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.numbers {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Virtual Keyboard using HTML5 &amp; JS Example</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Codeconvey" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Style CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>





  <section>
    <div class="rt-container">
      <div class="col-rt-12">
        <div class="Scriptcontent">
          <h1>Click Here to Type</h1>
          <textarea class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea>

          <script src="js/keyboard.js"></script>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Analytics -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a `toggle` variable to toggle between symbols and numbers -

```js
const keyLayout = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "backspace",
  "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
  "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",
  "toggle", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
  "space"
];
const SymbolLayout = [
  "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "backspace",
  "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p",
  "caps", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",
  "toggle", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "?",
  "space"
];

let symbol = false;

const Keyboard = {
  elements: {
    main: null,
    keysContainer: null,
    keys: []
  },

  eventHandlers: {
    oninput: null,
    onclose: null
  },

  properties: {
    value: "",
    capsLock: false
  },

  init() {
    // Create main elements
    this.elements.main = document.createElement("div");
    this.elements.keysContainer = document.createElement("div");

    // Setup main elements
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard", "keyboard--hidden");
    this.elements.keysContainer.classList.add("keyboard__keys");
    this.setLayout(keyLayout);

    // Add to DOM
    this.elements.main.appendChild(this.elements.keysContainer);
    document.body.appendChild(this.elements.main);

    // Automatically use keyboard for elements with .use-keyboard-input
    document.querySelectorAll(".use-keyboard-input").forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener("focus", () => {
        this.open(element.value, currentValue => {
          element.value = currentValue;
        });
      });
    });
  },
  setLayout(layout) {
    this.elements.keysContainer.innerHTML = "";
    this.elements.keysContainer.appendChild(this._createKeys(layout));
    this.elements.keys = this.elements.keysContainer.querySelectorAll(".keyboard__key");
  },
  _createKeys(layout) {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // Creates HTML for an icon
    const createIconHTML = (icon_name) => {
      return `<i class="material-icons">${icon_name}</i>`;
    };

    layout.forEach(key => {
      const keyElement = document.createElement("button");
      const insertLineBreak = ["backspace", "p", "enter", "?"].indexOf(key) !== -1;


      // Add attributes/classes
      keyElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
      keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key");

      switch (key) {
        case "backspace":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("backspace");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value = this.properties.value.substring(0, this.properties.value.length - 1);
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "caps":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide", "keyboard__key--activatable");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_capslock");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this._toggleCapsLock();
            keyElement.classList.toggle("keyboard__key--active", this.properties.capsLock);
          });

          break;

        case "enter":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("keyboard_return");

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += "\n";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "space":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--extra-wide");
          keyElement.innerHTML = createIconHTML("space_bar");
          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {

            this.properties.value += " ";
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;

        case "toggle":
          keyElement.classList.add("keyboard__key--wide");
          keyElement.innerText = symbol ? "123" : "!#*$";

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            symbol = !symbol;
            const layout = symbol ? SymbolLayout : keyLayout;
            this.setLayout(layout, symbol);
          });
          break;

        default:
          keyElement.textContent = key.toLowerCase();

          keyElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.properties.value += this.properties.capsLock ? key.toUpperCase() : key.toLowerCase();
            this._triggerEvent("oninput");
          });

          break;
      }

      fragment.appendChild(keyElement);

      if (insertLineBreak) {
        fragment.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      }
    });

    return fragment;
  },

  _triggerEvent(handlerName) {
    if (typeof this.eventHandlers[handlerName] == "function") {
      this.eventHandlers[handlerName](this.properties.value);
    }
  },

  _toggleCapsLock() {
    this.properties.capsLock = !this.properties.capsLock;

    for (const key of this.elements.keys) {
      if (key.childElementCount === 0) {
        key.textContent = this.properties.capsLock ? key.textContent.toUpperCase() : key.textContent.toLowerCase();
      }
    }
  },

  open(initialValue, oninput, onclose) {
    this.properties.value = initialValue || "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.remove("keyboard--hidden");
  },

  close() {
    this.properties.value = "";
    this.eventHandlers.oninput = oninput;
    this.eventHandlers.onclose = onclose;
    this.elements.main.classList.add("keyboard--hidden");
  }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  Keyboard.init();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url(/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: rgb(54, 49, 49);
}

.use-keyboard-input {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.678);
  border: 2px solid rgb(107, 104, 104);
  border-radius: 10%;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.keyboard {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: transparent;
  user-select: none;
  transition: bottom 0.4s;
}

.keyboard--hidden {
  bottom: -100%;
}

.keyboard__keys {
  text-align: center;
}

.keyboard__key {
  height: 45px;
  width: 6%;
  max-width: 90px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(218, 190, 218, 0.589);
  color: #0c0101;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.keyboard__key::after {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.keyboard__key:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}

.keyboard__key--wide {
  width: 12%;
}

.keyboard__key--extra-wide {
  width: 36%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.keyboard__key--dark {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.numbers {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Virtual Keyboard using HTML5 &amp; JS Example</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Codeconvey" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>





  <section>
    <div class="rt-container">
      <div class="col-rt-12">
        <div class="Scriptcontent">
          <h1>Click Here to Type</h1>
          <textarea class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Analytics -->

</body>

</html>
```